# StreamReader doesn't take string?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to read a file with a StreamReader, but I get an error for using `path`

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to System.IO.Stream

even though it's clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx), that you **should** be able to use a string.
What am I missing here?

```
public MyClass Load(String path)
{
    try
    {
        // exception in this line, `path` is underlined with red
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path)) 
        {
            String line = reader.ReadLine();
// ... etc
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter Marked it via edit.

Comment: show us ur 'path'

Comment: Why would that matter? It's passed as an argument. The function declaration doesn't know OR rely on knowing the path exactly.

Comment: Provided code should work  - can you show more context of this sample?

Comment: @Fabio What would you need? I really have no idea where things could've gone wrong.

Comment: Is this a compile time error, or a runtime error?

Comment: @ColinM Compile time.

Comment: According to the [example code note](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7): *The constructor [using string] used in this example is not supported for use in Windows Store Apps.*

Comment: Also if you look in the Version Information section for the [constructor using stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_4), it specifically mentions the Universal Windows Platform (which isn't mentioned in the one using string)

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you, compiler seems to be at rest with this solution.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell if you got your answer or not but the proper syntax for UWP is below:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filenamestring, FileMode.Open)))
```